# space above and below the text within a cell in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, cell, cellcolor, cellspace

In the following simple table:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}%per la flowchart
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{caption}  %per aggiungere captions al PRISMA ed evitare il floating delle tavole
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{subfig} %per figure multiple


\usepackage{amsmath}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice


\usepackage[style=vancouver,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, doi=false]{biblatex}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pdfpages}%per inserire pdf multipagina
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}%multicolonna
\usepackage{enumitem}%mi serve per gli elenchi semza punto
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{diagbox} %per le celle diagonali delle tabelle
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}%toglie i riquadri rossi intorno a hyperlinks come toc e citazioni e ne ridefinisce alcuni in blu





\begin{document}
\centering

\fontsize{11pt}{10.25pt}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    
    \toprule
    
    \cellcolor{DodgerBlue4}\color{white}{PICO 1F}& \setlength\extrarowheight{15pt} \cellcolor{DodgerBlue2}\color{white}\parbox{0.65\textwidth}{Nel trattamento dei pazienti con ernia parastomale (P) dovrebbe essere utilizzata la tecnica chirurgica laparoscopica (I) o a cielo aperto (C)? 
        O= Mortalità, morbilità, recidiva, qualità della vita, durata ricovero, dolore postoperatorio, costi} \\
    \midrule
    
    \cellcolor{DeepSkyBlue4}\color{white}{RACCOMANDAZIONE}  &  \cellcolor{DeepSkyBlue3}\color{white}\parbox{0.65\textwidth}{Per il trattamento  dei pazienti con laparocele parastomale, il panel suggerisce di utilizzare il trattamento laparoscopico in alternativa a quello a cielo aperto. \\ CONDIZIONATA A FAVORE} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\raggedright
\end{document}
```

I would like to have more space in the cells above and below the text. The color, of course should fill that empty space too.
I tried several options and I searched on StackExchange but I could not find a solution

Comment: Off-topic: What are you trying to achieve with `\fontsize{11pt}{10.25pt}`? It's very unusual, to put it mildly, to have the second argument of `\fontsize` to be smaller than the first.

Comment: I do not remember where did I find the suggestion; however, if I eliminate the second argument the text go back to double spacing (the default spacing of the document). I had also tried other solutions to reduce the spacing within the cell, but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cell colors are solid (and quite dark, in my opinion), there's really no need at all for either vertical *or* horizontal rules. Instead, do insert typographic struts, along the lines shown in the code below.

I'd also letterspace the all-caps terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\usepackage[table,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
%%%%%\usepackage{times} % no need, since `mathptmx` is a Times Roman clone as well
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz}%per la flowchart
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{caption}  %per aggiungere captions al PRISMA ed evitare il floating delle tavole
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{subfig} %per figure multiple

\usepackage{amsmath}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice
\usepackage{amssymb,
            %%%amsfonts, %% 'amssymb' loads 'amsfonts' automatically
            textcomp}%aggiunto per le tabelle dell'appendice

\usepackage[style=vancouver,citestyle=numeric-comp, 
            sorting=none,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, 
            doi=false]{biblatex}

%%%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pdfpages}%per inserire pdf multipagina
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}%multicolonna
\usepackage{enumitem}%mi serve per gli elenchi semza punto
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{diagbox} %per le celle diagonali delle tabelle
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}%toglie i riquadri rossi intorno a hyperlinks come toc e citazioni e ne ridefinisce alcuni in blu

%% new code:

%% create typographic struts
%% (cf. Claudio Beccari, "Correct spacing for tables and arrays", 
%% TeX and TUG News 1993 (Vol. 2, No. 3), p. 10)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}       % Top strut,    height: 2.9ex
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut, depth:  1.2ex
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut}         % Top and bottom strut

\usepackage{letterspace} % for '\textls' macro 


\begin{document}

\begin{center} % <-- new
\singlespacing % <-- new

%%%%%\fontsize{11pt}{10.25pt}\selectfont %

\begin{tabular}{ll}
    
 \cellcolor{DodgerBlue4}\color{white}{\textls{PICO 1F}\Tstrut}& 
 \cellcolor{DodgerBlue2}\color{white}\parbox[t]{0.65\textwidth}{%
   Nel trattamento dei pazienti con ernia parastomale (P) dovrebbe 
   essere utilizzata la tecnica chirurgica laparoscopica (I) o a 
   cielo aperto (C)?  O= Mortalità, morbilità, recidiva, qualità 
   della vita, durata ricovero, dolore postoperatorio, costi\Bstrut} \\
    
 \cellcolor{DeepSkyBlue4}\color{white}{\textls{RACCOMANDAZIONE}\Tstrut}  &    
 \cellcolor{DeepSkyBlue3}\color{white}\parbox[t]{0.65\textwidth}{%
    Per il trattamento  dei pazienti con laparocele parastomale, il 
    panel suggerisce di utilizzare il trattamento laparoscopico in 
    alternativa a quello a cielo aperto. \\ 
    \textls{CONDIZIONATA A FAVORE}\TBstrut} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}  % <-- new

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! Just two additional comments: 1. You mention that the colors are quite dark in your opinion. What color would you use? 2. In my rendering, the text on the left is very close to the border of the cell, much closer than in your example

Comment: Actually, looking better, in my table using your code I have the text of the upper right cell moved a little on the right, so that it almost touch the lateral border, while the text of the bottom right cell is moved to the center as far as the middle border of the cell. Therefore, the space is appropriate on the center, in the upper, and on the lateral border, on the lower cell. I would include an image but the `ctrl G` apparently does not work.

Comment: @FabioCampanile - I'm afraid I couldn't quite understand your comments. Let's start step by step. If you take the code above and compile it on your machine, what happens? Do you get the same image as the one shown above, or do you get something different? Please advise.

Comment: I get a very similar image. However, in the upper right cell the text is very close to the outer margin, while in the lower right cell it is very close to the left margin of the cell. I could probably upload the image in an "answer", but I cannot do it in a comment.

Comment: @FabioCampanile - Yes, please edit your original query and post a screenshot of what you're getting. When you make that edit, please also say which operating system and which TeX distribution you run.

Comment: I found the problem: there was a piece of the old code left (`\setlength\extrarowheight{15pt}`)

Comment: I would still love your advice about the colors

Comment: @FabioCampanile - About the choice of colors: Obviously, all kinds of considerations will have gone into your specific choice of colors, so it would presumptuous of me to tell you outright that some other color combination would be "better" (other than that the current colors seem quite dark...). If you're ok staying with the `DodgerBlue` and `DeepSkyBlue` color families, the only suggestion I have is that you might try choosing "color numbers" that are 1 less than the current number choices, e.g., `DeepSkyBlue2` instead of ` DeepSkyBlue3, etc.

Comment: The result looks great! Can you just tell me what [t] stands for, in the parbox options? I have seen that the struts do not appear without it, but I do not understand why

Comment: @FabioCampanile - The `[t]` option (twice in the right-hand column) is there to inform LaTeX that the material in the other columns (here: just one column) should be top-aligned.